# Question on sequence converging to $\sup S$ of $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

To show there exists a sequence in $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ that converges to $\sup S$ we can say the following:

Let $n$ be any positive integer. Then $\sup S -\frac{1}{n}$ is not an 
upper bound of $S$, so there is some $a_n\in S$ with $\sup S \geq a_n>\sup S-\frac{1}{n}$. Now the sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $\sup S$.

**Question**

Why do we need to take $(a_n)$ as the sequence. Why can't we simply say $\sup S - \frac{1}{n}$ itself as the sequence that converges to $\sup S$?

Comment: Who says that $\sup S -\frac{1}{n}\in S$?

Answer (score 4):

The question asks for a sequence in $S$. The terms $a_n$ are all necessarily in $S$ by definition of the supremum, but the terms $x_n = \sup S - \frac{1}{n}$ are not necessarily in $S$.

Comment: You only know there is some element bigger than it, in $S$, otherwise $\sup(S) - \frac{1}{n}$ would have been a strictly smaller lower bound. So we can pick such an $x_n \in S$. Say in the case of $S = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$ we'd have to construct a sequence that is constantly $2$, as there is a gap between the sup and the rest of $S$, e.g.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to construct an example where your construct won't work. Just take $S = \{0\}$.

$0$ will trivially be the least upper bound for $S$ and $a_n = 0-1/n$ won't be in $S$ (since $-1/n\ne 0$).

In fact for any such predefined convergent sequence $a_n$ you can construct a set $S$ that has $\sup S = \lim a_n$ as least upper bound, but $a_n\notin S$ (just take $S = \{ x: x<\lim a_n \land x \ne a_n \}$)